# Product Distribution with Copula

Tags: distributions

I am trying to create a joint probability function that is of the form:

f(a,b,c)=f1(a).f2(b).f3(c).copula

where

```
copula=CopulaDistribution[{"MultivariateT",R,2},{f1, f2, f3}]
```

and

f1, f2, f3 are marginal distributions.

I do this by using the code

```
ProductDistribution[copula,f1,f2,f3]
```

Clearly, I should be able to simulate from this product distribution (and I am). However, my problem is that Mathematica thinks there are 6 variables (3 from copula, and 3 from the marginals). This obviously should not be the case as there should only be 3 variables corresponding to the marginals

What can I do to rectify this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to combine the four distributions `copula,f1,f2,f3` by means of `ProductDistribution`.  However, `ProductDistribution` is meant to "represent the joint distribution with independent component distributions", according to its documentation.  Consequently, the variables of each of your four distributions must be independent, for a total of six.

Perhaps, you should use `TransformedDistribution` instead of `ProductDistribution`, as described in [69347](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69347/joint-distribution-with-a-constant), although it is difficult to know without a more complete understanding of what you are trying to accomplish.