# Random Variate from a transformed Distribution

Tags: distributions

I would like to simulate random variates from a transformed distribution of a joint distribution and a constant.

i.e.

```
joint=ProductDistribution[NormalDistribution[],BetaDistribution[1,2],BetaDistribution[2,2]];
transform=TransformedDistribution[3*joint....]
```

I am unsure how to complete the transformed distribution code to put in the variables.

Comment: Please, when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
joint = ProductDistribution[NormalDistribution[], BetaDistribution[1, 2], BetaDistribution[2, 2]];
q = TransformedDistribution[{x, y, z} w, {{x, y, z} \[Distributed]  joint, 
                                          w \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[]}]
ListPlot3D@RandomVariate[joint, 100]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for the help. Am I allowed to just say w is distributed by 3? I have an exact constant I would like to use.

Comment: @Jim Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by _"w is distributed by 3"_

Answer (score 1):

```
joint = ProductDistribution[NormalDistribution[], BetaDistribution[1, 2], BetaDistribution[2, 2]];
td = TransformedDistribution[3 {x, y, z} , Distributed[{x, y, z}, joint]];

Through@{Mean, Variance}@td
(* {{0,1,3/2}, {9,1/2,9/20}} *)

PDF[td, {x, y, z}]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot3D[RandomVariate[td, 50]]
```

[image]

**See also:** [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/69350/125) to a closely related question by the same OP.